# socketIO-client - RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to communicate between a node.js application and python using socket.io with the socketIO-client 0.5.1 library on the python side.   Below are the two code chunks:

```
var http = require('http').createServer();
http.listen(6000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http, { log: false });
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
    var counter = 0;
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        eventEmitter.on('observe', function(message){
            socket.emit('sendVoltage', {});
        });

        socket.on('voltage', function (data) {
            console.log(counter + " - " + data.voltage);
            if (counter++ < 500) {
                eventEmitter.emit('observe', '');
            }
        });
        eventEmitter.emit('observe', '');
    });
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time, signal, sys
from Adafruit_ADS1x15 import ADS1x15
from socketIO_client import SocketIO
ADS1115 = 0x01  # 16-bit ADC
adc = ADS1x15(ic=ADS1115)
socketIO = SocketIO('chair01', 6000)
def on_voltage_response(*args):
    print 'on_voltage_response', args

def on_sendVoltage(*args):
    voltage = adc.readADCSingleEnded(0, 4096, 250) / 1000
    print "Emitting voltage"
    socketIO.emit('voltage', {'voltage': voltage}, on_voltage_response)
    socketIO.wait_for_callbacks(seconds=1)
    print "Voltage emitted"

socketIO.on('sendVoltage', on_sendVoltage)
socketIO.wait(seconds=1)
```

When the `sendVoltage` message is detected the `on_sendVoltage` function is executed, the voltage message is emitted, but control is never returned from the emit.   The next message comes in, and the next etc.with never a return. At some point, it dies with too many recursive calls.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling socketIO.wait_for_callbacks() in the on_sendVoltage function.  Your main should instead be something like this:

```
state = 'waiting'
while state == 'waiting':
    self.socket.wait(seconds=1)
```

That will keep Python running waiting forever but your callbacks will still run.  You can change the state in your callbacks if you want to do something else.